# How can i connect to MySql database to create a mobile application?

Tags: android, mysql, ios, mobile-application

I have a script in java that works like a crawler and saves data in MySql DB. What i want to do is build a Mobile App(Andriod/ios) which will connect to mysql database retrieve results and just show it to the user.

What is the best approach to this ? I tried to use Flex UI with PHP as my server client but was hoping to know if there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest would be to make android fetch a page in XML, typically on the server and display its contents(If displaying contets is your desired result).

#### else

You need to implement a script on your server, your POST interacts with that script and inturn that script works with your database.

A typical scenario will be:

Java HTTP POST ~~~> PHP ~~~~> MySql.

PHP will as well help you encode the result in JSON and post it back to your client.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jdbc or jtds library to connect android app with mysql

I used jdts library for connecting mssql db using android app.
http://jtds.sourceforge.net

For mysql jdbc might work